# My Minecraft Horse Jumps Too High

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I used this command to summon my desired horse. Everything I like, expect one thing... It jumps too high (outrageously high):

```
/summon horse ~ ~1 ~ {Tame:1,Variant:260,Attributes:[{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:0.3375},{Name:horse.jumpStrength,Base:1}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:5,Duration:1000000},{Id:8,Amplifier:80,Duration:1000000}]}
```

I just want to know how to fix this problem with the jump strength of my horse to jump at least 6 blocks high... but, no higher than 10 blocks.

Answer (score -2):

Normally the horses jumpe to 3 but it is possible that you find more powerful. You can even reproduce a horse running fast with one which jumps high, to have a mix of both.